# Can't pass FORM data to PHP file

Tags: php, html, forms, cookies

I had this working for a friend, then he changed provider, and now nothing works, from all the tests i've made, the submit button should pass the data to the php file, but when the php file runs it gets nothing.

this is the FORM code on the html file:

```
<form id="lista" action="lista.php" method="post">
<input name="cf_name" type="text" size="50" hidden="yes" class="obscure">
<input name="cf_email" type="text" size="50" hidden="yes" class="obscure">
<textarea name="cf_message" cols="45" rows="10" hidden="yes" class="obscure"></textarea>
<input type="image" name="lista" value="Enviar Lista por Email" src="imagens/lista_email.png" width="40" height="40"  onclick="this.form.elements['cf_message'].value =  lista_mail;this.form.elements['cf_name'].value = prompt('Escreva o seu nome:',      '');this.form.elements['cf_email'].value = prompt('Escreva o seu email:', '');">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar" hidden="yes" class="obscure">
</form>
```

before, when he clicked on submit, the popups appear to ask for name and email, and the php file would get those values, now nothing gets there.

Here is the PHP file:

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {

$smtpinfo['host'] = 'localhost';
$smtpinfo['port'] = '25';
$smtpinfo['auth'] = true;
$smtpinfo['username'] = 'xxx';
$smtpinfo['password'] = 'xxx';

$nome = $_POST['cf_name'];
$email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$mensagem = $_POST['cf_message'];

require_once "Mail.php";

$body = "Nome: ".$nome;
$body.= "\n";
$body.= nl2br($mensagem);

$headers = array ('From' => $email,
'To' => $smtpinfo["username"],
'Subject' => 'Encomenda Website');

$mail_object = Mail::factory('smtp', $smtpinfo);

$mail = $mail_object->send($smtpinfo["username"], $headers, $body);

if ( PEAR::isError($mail) ) {
echo ("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
echo ('<b><font color="FFFF00">Mensagem enviada com sucesso para </b>' . $email . '<br><br></font>');
}}
?>
```

this PHP works properly on a contact form on the same site, so is ok, the problem seems to get the data from html form to php, because he never passes the "IF POST submit is set", don't know why, because you press the submit button before arriving to this file.

Can anyone please help? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried dumping the `$_POST` array? Also, since you have changed providers, can you run a  simple PHP script and just verify that PHP is set up appropriately?

Comment: the name of the php file is still the same ? I mean still lista.php  ?

Comment: Have you tried to give a name attribute to the form and use the isset on its name? And, moreover, why the submit button has an hidden=true attribute? I don't even think hidden=true exists!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an image as the submit (not the hidden button). So rename your image-input to "submit" and it should work.

```
<input type="image" name="submit" value="Enviar Lista por Email" ........
```

If you're using `<input type="image" ....` this acts as an alternative submit-button. So you can get rid of your hidden button and rename your image-input "submit".

Comment: it was as simple as that, good catch, thanks for the help, and the hidden wasn't effecting that, i kept them hidden with success. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In your form you have

```
<input type="image" name="lista" value="Enviar Lista por Email" src="imagens/lista_email.png" width="40" height="40"  onclick="this.form.elements['cf_message'].value =  lista_mail;this.form.elements['cf_name'].value = prompt('Escreva o seu nome:',      '');this.form.elements['cf_email'].value = prompt('Escreva o seu email:', '');">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar" hidden="yes" class="obscure">
```

but the submit element is hidden, so you are only seeing the image with `name="lista"`.

Then in PHP you are checking `$_POST['submit']` but actually when you are clicking the image you are sending `$_POST['lista']`.

So it's just depends what would like to use, the submit or image or both.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var lista_mail = 'super';
</script>

<form id="lista" action="lista.php" method="post">
<input name="cf_name" type="text" size="50" hidden="yes" class="obscure">
<input name="cf_email" type="text" size="50" hidden="yes" class="obscure">
<textarea name="cf_message" cols="45" rows="10" hidden="yes" class="obscure"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar Lista por Email" src="imagens/lista_email.png" width="40" height="40"  `enter code here`onclick="this.form.elements['cf_message'].value =  `enter code here`lista_mail;this.form.elements['cf_name'].value = prompt('Escreva o seu nome:',      '');this.form.elements['cf_email'].value = prompt('Escreva o seu email:', '');">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar" hidden="yes" class="obscure">
</form>
```

If you want to give image to submit button give as background with css. I have changed the type=image to submit , name='lista' to submit as in post u r checking in php for $_post['submit'], one more thing is you are missing that javascript parameter lista_mail, make sure it's predefined, i have defined it in script tag